# problemas con teclado en android con juego web

Tags: javascript, html, html5

tengo una pequeña app web de un juego de ahorcado que desarrolle para un curso que voy llevando mi problema es el siguiente puse una funcion para que capture las teclas presionadas y funciona bien en pc pero cuando estoy de un telefono al no haber inputs no se abre el teclado, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de abrir el teclado al ingresar a la pagina y abrirlo a disposicion con un boton talvez el codigo para capturar letras es el sgt :
con esto llamo la funcion al precionar el boton comenzar partida

```
function comenzarPartida(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    if(!$resultado.classList.contains('hiden')){
        $resultado.style.zIndex ='0'
        ocultar($resultado)
    }
    if($partida.classList.contains('hiden')){
        ocultar($tematica)
        mostrar($partida)
    }
    borrarLetrasUsadas()
    eliminarRayitas()
    event.preventDefault()
    reiniciarJuego()
    cambiarEscenario('panoramica3')
    document.onkeypress = capturarCaracter;
    let palabra = sortearPalabra()
    let palabraJunta= palabra.toUpperCase().replace(' ','')
    crearRayitas(palabra)
    arrayCorrectas(palabraJunta)
    function capturarCaracter(evObject){
        let caracter = evObject.key;
        CompararCaracter(caracter,palabraJunta, palabra)
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**No puedes** abrirlo así sin más, la única forma por las **políticas y seguridad**, imagina que cuando abras una web te abra el teclado y detecte todo lo que hagas y no te permita cerrar el teclado, no tendría sentido y sería inseguro.

Deberías trabajar con el **touch** y los **gestos** como cualquier juego móvil, detectar si se está abriendo desde un móvil y si es así trabajas con lo antes mencionado.